# ClassNotFound exception in the catch clause

Tags: java, exception, classloader, classnotfound

```
public class dummy {
    public static void main(String[] args) { System.out.println("hello world"); }

    public void init() {
        //"dummy2" class defined in a different jar
        dummy2 d = new dummy2(); 
        try { d.run(); } 
        //"dummyexception" class defined in a different jar
        catch (dummyexception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }

    public void init2() {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //"dummy2" class defined in a different jar
                dummy2 d = new dummy2(); 
                try { d.run(); } 
                //"dummyexception" class defined in a different jar
                catch (dummyexception e) { e.printStackTrace(); } 
                catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }        
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Now before running I removed the dependent jar from the classpath.
I get '`ClassNotFoundException`' for the class '`dummyexception`' being referenced in the method `init()` and not for the usage in the method `init2()`. Interestingly no '`ClassNotFoundException`' for the class '`dummy2`' being referrenced in the method `init()`.

Comment: Samples of your code are worth a thousand words here.

Comment: who is calling `init()` or `init2()` ?

Comment: @RaviTrivedi suppose init() and init2() have never called

Comment: @taky, sir, then he should not get this error because there is no dynamic linking happening only because methods are not being used. which means JVM, in the class file, does not need to convert string symbolic references to actual pointers to these methods.

Comment: @RaviTrivedi I was wandered, but method try to class in catch declaration, when you load the class. Probably it is related with exception handling mechanism in JVM internals.

Answer (score 0):

> Now before running I removed the dependent jar from the classpath. I get 'ClassNotFoundException' for the class 'dummyexception' being referenced in the method init() and not for the usage in the method init2().

Class `dummy2` will load only when init method will executed. Despite `dummyexcetion` is a catch parameter, so JVM process this class, as java method. Full name for `dummyexception` class is placed into jvm *.class file [constant_pool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se5.0/html/ClassFile.doc.html) and JVM check class availability before `dummy` was loaded.

Let's consider an example:

```
public class Dummy {
    
    public void init(){
        DummyExternal dummy = new DummyExternal();
        try {
            dummy.run();
        } catch(DummyException e) {
        } catch(Exception e){ }
    }
    
    public void init2(){
        new Runnable() {            
            @Override
            public void run() {
                DummyExternal dummy = new DummyExternal();
                try {
                    dummy.run();
                } catch(DummyException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch(Exception e){}
            }
        }.run();
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("hello world");
    }

}



public class DummyException extends RuntimeException {
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2049347223914508696L;

    static {
        System.out.println("DummyException");
    }

}


public class DummyExternal implements Runnable {
    
    static {
        System.out.println("DummyExternal");
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("DummyExternal");
    }

}
```

In output we will have:

> -rw-r--r--  1 taky  staff   756B May 19 08:26 Dummy$1.class
>
> -rw-r--r--  1 taky  staff   956B May 19 08:26 Dummy.class
>
> -rw-r--r--  1 taky  staff   545B May 19 08:26 DummyException.class
>
> -rw-r--r--  1 taky  staff   569B May 19 08:26 DummyExternal.class

Command `java Dummy` print `hello world`. So no `DummyExternal` or `DummyException` class was loaded.

Remove `DummyExternal` class file: `rm DummyExternal.class`. Result of `java Dummy` do not change.

Let's remove `DummyException` class file: `rm DummyException.class`.

And after execution of `java Dummy` we receive interesting stack trace.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: DummyException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2442)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2685)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1620)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: DummyException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 6 more
```

This behavior is because of exception handling mechanism. If class is the catch parameter generate exception handlers which should be resolved when exception handled. Exception handling mechanism is similar with method invocation and ClassLoader resolve `DummyException` from the constant pool before class loading.

Comment: agree to your point. But the most important question is why do i get 'classnotfoundexception' for the class 'dummyexception' and not the class 'dummy2'. Both these classes are in a dependent jar which is not available at runtime. And also i tried commenting "init()" method alone this time i did not get any exception at all!!

Comment: thanks Taky. But if we comment init() method there wont be any 'classnotfoundexception' for init2(), is it because of anonymous class instantiated in init2()?

Comment: @karts yes, anonymous will be loaded only when init2() will be executed first time.

Answer (score 0):

Speculation here - the methods are being validated in lexographical order, and for each method the exception handlers are validated before the local variables.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you first compiled your class by providing all the dependent `jar` files. And which is why your class compiled successfully. And then you removed all the dependent `jar` files before running your program. And then you got an error.

**My take on this:**

According to me, you should not get any error because `init()` and `init2()`, which use *dependent* jars, are not being called by any function.

**What is the relation between functions not being called and error generation ?**

When you compile your classes, **JVM** creates class files. In those class files, **JVM** creates `symbolic string references` to calling methods and classes by searching classes in the `classpath`. If it does not find referenced classes, you will get errors at compile time and your classes will not compile. If it finds it then your compile is successful and then **JVM** adds those `symbolic string references` inside the class file. There is no actual `pointer to methods and classes` at this point of time.

Now, when you run your program, Your calls to methods are found in the form of those `symbolic string references` in the class file. At this point, these `symbolic references` are converted into `actual pointers to classes and methods`. At this point, your `class loader` will search for those dependent classes **`only if`** the referenced methods are being called from some method. If it does not find the dependent classes in the classpath, error is generated. **Note:** `class loader` will not search for dependent classes if the methods are not being called. `Symbolic instructions` will be ignored and no error will be generated.

**What happens in your case ?**

I don't see your `init()` and `init2()` being called by anyone. Which means `class loader` does not need to find the `dependent jars` and `create pointer to these methods`. Which means you should not get any error **`Unless`** something is calling these methods.